# A Plague Tale: Innocence: Getting all upgrades in one play-through

Tags: achievements, a-plague-tale-innocence

I have managed to get all the achievements for the game as well as all the collectibles and all the upgrades, but it took two play-throughs to do so. I am currently replaying A Plague Tale: Innocence again to see if I can get all the collectibles and upgrades with one play-through.

In order to attempt this, I looked at a bunch of tutorials. The ones I have found all caution against doing the alchemy upgrades, because it jeopardizes the ability to upgrade the sling and equipment upgrades.

To possibly achieve this, I'd have to play thoroughly. It means that I have to be absolutely stingy with my resources and explore every corner, especially for the rare items such as leather, cloth and cord.

Has anyone managed to get all of the above in a single play-through successfully?

Comment: I replayed, and got short 2 pieces of leather :-( I guess I will wait a bit and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to multiple people on the [PSNprofiles forum](https://forum.psnprofiles.com/topic/74752-is-there-enough-resources-to-upgrade-both-sling-equipment/), you can get all upgrades in one playthrough:

- > I can also confirm you can get all of the sling, equipment and alchemy upgrades in one playthrough, whilst crafting a fuck load of ammo. Just be very thorough in your looting. <sup>[source](https://forum.psnprofiles.com/topic/74752-is-there-enough-resources-to-upgrade-both-sling-equipment/?do=findComment&comment=1848103)</sup>
- > Can confirm, I upgraded everything, even Alchemy by the end of the game and still found a few more resources to spare through the last chapter.  <sup>[source](https://forum.psnprofiles.com/topic/74752-is-there-enough-resources-to-upgrade-both-sling-equipment/?do=findComment&comment=1868665)</sup>
- > [..] I ended up finding enough resources anyways to upgrade everything. Just be thorough when going through areas and upgrade your carrying capacity 1st.
  > The game tends to want you to upgrade somethings ahead of others. Don't pass on things because your waiting to upgrade something else.  <sup>[source](https://forum.psnprofiles.com/topic/74752-is-there-enough-resources-to-upgrade-both-sling-equipment/?do=findComment&comment=2007235)</sup>

And so on.
Apparently you mostly have to be stingy with crafting ammunition, especially Somnium and Luminosa, and, of course, check every nook and cranny for resources. And — obviously — it's wise to upgrade Pocket first, as it allows you to take more resources.